# How to determine if a function is jointly convex?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

I always struggle when trying to prove if a function with multiple variables is jointly convex or not.

**Here is an example of a matrix factorization problem that is not jointly convex.**

$\frac{1}{2} \sum_{(d,n) \subset observed} (x_{dn} - (WZ^T)_{dn})^2 + \frac{\lambda_w}{2}||W||^2_{Frob} + \frac{\lambda_z}{2}||Z||^2_{Frob} $

I am able to see that it is convex if we fix one variable either W or Z. But

1. How can I show that it is (or not) jointly convex ?
2. Are there any tips and tricks to determine if a function of multiple variables are jointly convex ?

**Another example that is jointly convex.** Page 27 of
http://alex.smola.org/teaching/berkeley2012/slides/8_Recommender.pdf

$\min_b \sum_{u,i} (r_{ui} - \mu - b_u - b_i)^2 + \lambda(\sum_u b_u^2 + \sum_i b_i^2)$

Comment: That font size is just too much for my aged retinas.

Comment: sorry editing. those are pictures

Comment: 1. If you have enough differentiability, set up the Hessian and check it is positive semidefinite.
2. Something with products is always bad news, as in your example. 
Finally, what is $(WZ^T){dn}$? Is there a trace missing?

Comment: but how do i differentiate the top equation

Comment: do i do a partial derivative wrt w and z and check its hessian ?